# Identifying INF values in a list and making it NULL

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list (here I'm considering it to be of equal elements) where some of the list elements have INF values in it. The list is defined as

```
cid <- c('X','Y','Z')
uid <- c('A','B','C','P','Q','R',NA)
mid <- c('1393','1398')
c1 <- c(5,4,6,5,1,10,Inf,15,18,13,19,Inf,Inf,2)
c2 <- c(15,18,13,19,Inf,Inf,2)
c3 <- c(Inf,1)
test <- list(cid,uid,mid,c1,c2,c3)
names(test) <- c('cid','uid','mid',"c1","c2","c3")

> test
$cid
[1] "X" "Y" "Z"

$uid
[1] "A" "B" "C" "P" "Q" "R" NA 

$mid
[1] "1393" "1398"

$c1
[1]   5   4   6   5   1  10 Inf  15  18  13  19 Inf Inf   2

$c2
[1]  15  18  13  19 Inf Inf   2

$c3
[1] Inf   1
```

Now I want to check whether the elements of the list have INF value present in them or not. If any of the element have INF value
1. Store that element name in a separate vector / list / dataframe (anything works)
2. Make that element in the original list NULL

To check infinite values in Dataframes columns I use **is.infinite()** in combination with sapply. Something like

```
inf_values <- sapply(df, function(x)any(is.infinite(x)))
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with list. I am currently using a for loop like

```
> for (i in 1:length(test)){
    inf_name_temp[i] = ifelse(sum(any(is.infinite(test[[i]]))) > 0,1,0)
}
> inf_name_temp
[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

My thinking is to get index value from inf_name_temp using

```
> which(inf_name_temp)
```

and then using apply, loop it to the list element to nullify the element which is NULL. Also, a temp_list is there to know which element had INF values

```
> inf_check <- apply(which(inf_name_temp==1),1,new_list)
> new_list <- function(x){
  temp_list <- test[[x]]
  test[[x]] <- NULL
  }
```

Error is

```
Error in apply(which(inf_name_temp == 1), 1, new_list) : 
dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Eventual goal is to get a list like

```
> test
$cid
[1] "X" "Y" "Z"

$uid
[1] "A" "B" "C" "P" "Q" "R" NA 

$mid
[1] "1393" "1398"

> temp_list
[1] "cid" "uid" "mid"
```

However, I'm not able to achieve that goal (probably know error is in apply as it cannot be used like this.). Any suggestions as to how we can do it or any other simple approach that I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the names of list elements which have an infinite value you can use `sapply`:

```
inf_names <- names(df)[sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.infinite(x)) > 0)]
```

To replace the infinite values in the list with `NULL` you can use `lapply` to return a list:

```
df <- lapply(df, function(x) {
                     x[is.infinite(x)] <- NULL
                     return(x)
                 })
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I don't know why when I was applying is.infinite() and sapply to the list it was not working.